# Is it possible to create a fat framework for iOS, Simulator, *and* Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a simple C library that I'd like to distribute as a single framework for all three platforms — iOS, Mac, and the iOS Simulator. I'm aware of the fact that it's possible to configure Xcode (or use `lipo`) to generate a fat framework that contains the arm architectures and the i386/x86 architectures, but from my testing it appears that the overlap between the shared architectures of the iOS Simulator and Mac leaves room for only one or the other (Xcode gives warnings when using the Mac x86_64/i386 binary compiled for the simulator.)

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, for the reason you mentioned (same arch for different platforms).

Comment: I figured — but wanting to know for sure. Thanks @LeoNatan!

Comment: If your project is open source, one target can contain all platforms, so you can go that road.

Comment: This might be possible with the new `xcframework` in [Xcode 11](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes?language=objc)

Comment: Thank you @TheNextman — that looks like the most promising solution. I found this [WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/) that describes it further. If you'd like to post what you've said as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @mattsven Please report back on how this works out! The procedure outlined in the WWDC talk is still rather elaborate and looks easy to get wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xcframework` is new in Xcode 11, and may make this possible. From the [Xcode 11 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes?language=objc):

> XCFramework make it possible to bundle a binary framework or library for multiple platforms —including iOS devices, iOS simulators, and Mac Catalyst — into a single distributable .xcframework bundle that your developers can use within their own applications. An .xcframework bundle can be added to an Xcode target’s Link Libraries phase and Xcode uses the right platform’s version of the included framework or library at build time.

And you already linked to the relevant talk from [WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/)

Comment: I've been able to develop a custom XCFramework with Xcode 11 (and now 12), and it's indeed a good way to support macOS, iOS, iOS Simulator and Mac Catalyst builds (although I haven't tried with plain-old C libraries). Here I've put an article (tutorial style) with my journey - maybe it helps someone: https://medium.com/swift-sections/xcframeworks-afd0b151d111